# Arrays of Objects: For each element in array 1, does an object value exist as a value in any of the objects in array 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays which contain objects in each element of the array.

```
var array1 = [{firstName: "John", lastName: "McDonald"}, 
              {firstName: "Sandy", lastName: "Johnson"},
              ....,];

var array2 = [{userName: "Donald"}, {userName: "John"},....,];
```

In psuedo-code, I want to do the following:

```
for each element in array1
    if (array1[i] == any userName in array2)
        ...
```

In plain english I want to look at each firstname in array1 and see if it exists at all in array2 as the value associated with the userName property.

Comment: So what's your question? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know this is exactly what you want, but you will get an idea how to do that.

```
var userExists = array1.map(function(person){
                  return array2.some(function(user){
                        return user.userName===person.firstName
                     })
                 })

console.log(userExists);
```

Here `userExists` will be an array which will contain booleans like, if firstname of element in `array1` matches any username in `array2` it will have `true` for that otherwise `false`.

**NOTE:-** `map` & `some` functions are not supported by IE8.

Comment: If you use `map` you might as well use `some` like `arr1.map(function(x){return arr2.some(function(y){return y.userName===x.firstName})})`

Comment: @elclanrs thanx, that was realy nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
    array1.foreach(x => {
        if (array2.filter(y => y.username === x.firstName || y.username === x.lastName).length >0){
           console.log(y.username);
         }
    });
```